# SUM SQL Data with Group By in one final Sum

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a data table like the following example. I want to get the Sum of the column 'price'.
The problem is, that i have the same data ('id') multiple times, which is updated from the program multiple times, there i only want the newest data entry.

f.e. the data

| id | price | updatedate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 **** | 20 | 11.07.2023 |
| 1 | 25 | 08.07.2023 |
| 1 | 85 | 06.07.2023 |
| 2 | 70 | 10.07.2023 |
| 2 **** | 15 | 11.07.2023 |
| 3 | 50 | 01.07.2023 |
| 3 **** | 90 | 11.07.2023 |
| 3 | 60 | 07.07.2023 |

So in this example, i want to sum the **** rows, because this are the newest data entrys for every id

I'm trying to search an SQL Function to get the sum of these values (price column), which is here
20 + 15  + 90 = **125**

If i try GROUP BY, the result is given in three rows for every id und sums up every data row with this id.

```
SELECT SUM (price) FROM table GROUP BY id
```

but that isn't working....

Comment: Use a CTE for the `GROUP BY id` with `MAX` to get the latest `updatedate`, then `JOIN` that CTE with the source table to get the `price` for the matching `id + updatedate` row.

Comment: Thanks Dai! Have you an example for the SQL Syntax here?

Comment: See the linked question that this has been closed as a duplicate-of.